# how to extract the rows which are not matching with df

Tags: r

```
df1

Date  
2014-01-01 01:01:00  
2014-01-01 01:02:00  
2014-01-01 01:03:00  

df2  
Date                      **name**  
2014-01-01 01:01:00        **p1**  
2014-01-01 01:03:00        **p1**  
2014-01-01 01:01:00        **p2**  
2014-01-01 01:02:00        **p2**
```

How do we get missing rows from df2 i.e
time series with minute 02 is missing for "p1" and 03 for p2

I have tried with below code

```
a=merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "Date", all.x = TRUE)
```

and getting only missind dates

o/p

```
Date                    **name**  
2014-01-01 01:02:00     **p1**  
2014-01-01 01:03:00     **p2**
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you format the code in your question a bit better so it's more readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(tidyverse) 
df2 %>% 
   semi_join(df1, by="Date") %>% 
   group_by(Date) %>%
   filter(n() < 2) %>% 
   mutate(Miss=ifelse(name== "p1", "p2", "p1"))
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
Groups: V1 [2]

                 Date   name  Miss
               <fctr> <fctr> <chr>
1 2014-01-01 01:02:00     p2    p1
2 2014-01-01 01:03:00     p1    p2
```

Comment: Thanks jimbou, how we can code  if we have N number of rows and names

Comment: Should be the same code as above. Please provide an example with more rows by editing your question, e.g. pasting the output of `dput(head(df1,20))` and `dput(head(df2,20))`